# Statistics of one hot encoded columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column titled `"label"`. It has three columns titled `featureA_1, featureA_2, featureA_3` respectively. These columns represent columns representing one hot encoded values of `featureA` (which can have three unique values.) Similarly, it also has two columns titled `featureB_1` and `featureB_2` respectively. These columns represent one hot encoded values of `featureB` (which can have two distinct values.)

Following is an example of the said dataframe

[image].

The above mentioned dataframe can be generated using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
dictt = {
    "label": ["cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "dog"],
    "featureA_1": [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    "featureA_2": [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "featureA_3": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    "featureB_1": [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    "featureB_2": [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dictt)
```

Because of one hot encoding, each row in the above dataframe will have the value 1 for only one of the feature values `featureA_1, featureA_2, featureA_3` and 0 for others. Similarly, each row will have value 1 for only one of the feature values `featureB_1` and `featureB_2` and zero for the other.

**I want to create a dataframe where I will have the percentage of entries in each label with feature values `featureA_1, featureA_2, featureA_3` and  percentage of entries in each label with feature values `featureB_1` and `featureB_2`.**

**I also want to have the standard deviations of those percentages of featureA value types and featureB value types.**

Following is an example of the dataframe that I desire to have:

[image]

**What is the most efficient way of doing this?** In my actual work, I will have dataframes with millions of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#aggregate mean for percentages of 1, because only 0, 1 values 
df = df1.groupby('label').mean().add_suffix('_perc').round(2)

#aggregate std witg ddof=0, because default pandas ddof=1
df2 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).std(ddof=0).add_suffix('_std').round(2)

#join together
df = pd.concat([df, df2],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
  label  featureA_1_perc  featureA_2_perc  featureA_3_perc  featureA_std  \
0   cat             0.60              0.2             0.20          0.19   
1   dog             0.67              0.0             0.33          0.27   

   featureB_1_perc  featureB_2_perc  featureB_std  
0             0.40             0.60          0.10  
1             0.67             0.33          0.17
```