# Compare pandas dataframe with one-hot encoded encoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes (say `df1` and `df2`).

In `df1`, I have a column titled `"label"` which denotes unique label values. No two rows in `df1` will have same `"label"` values.  It has three columns titled `featureA_1, featureA_2, featureA_3` respectively which each of which contains float values. These columns represents possible feature values of `featureA`. Similarly, this dataframe also has two columns titled `featureB_1` and `featureB_2` which contain float values and represent unique feature values of `featureB`. Additionally, it has two columns which contain standard deviations of attribute values of `featureA` and `featureB`. These are titled `featureA_std` and `featureB_std`.

Following is an example of `df1`.

[image]

`df1` can be created using the following snippet:

```
dict1 = {
    "label": ["cat", "dog"],
    "featureA_1": [0.60, 0.67],
    "featureA_2": [0.20, 0.00],
    "featureA_3": [0.20, 0.33],
    "featureA_std": [0.189, 0.274],
    "featureB_1": [0.40, 0.67],
    "featureB_2": [0.60, 0.33],
    "featureB_std": [0.10, 0.17],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

In `df2`, I have the same columns as `df1` except for the standard deviation columns. Here, column titled `"label"` can have multiple values with the same string value. Each row here represents a sample. The values of `featureA_1, featureA_2, featureA_3` denote one hot encoded values of `featureA`. And `featureB_1` and `featureB_2` represent one hot encoded values of `featureB.` Because of one hot encoding, each row in the above dataframe will have the value 1 for only one of the feature values featureA_1, featureA_2, featureA_3 and 0 for others. Similarly, each row will have value 1 for only one of the feature values featureB_1 and featureB_2 and zero for the other.

Following is an example of `df2.`

[image]

`df2` can be created using the following code snippet.

```
dict2 = {
    "label": ["cat", "cat", "dog"],
    "featureA_1": [1, 0, 0],
    "featureA_2": [0, 1, 0],
    "featureA_3": [0, 0, 1],
    "featureB_1": [0, 0, 1],
    "featureB_2": [1, 1, 0],
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

**I want to compare each row of `df2` with `df1` and find the value of `featureA` (i.e. `featureA_1` , `featureA_2`, `featureA_3`) in `df1` which corresponds to the corresponding column in `df2` with value = 1. I want to divide corresponding standard deviation (i.e. the column `featureA_std`) by this value. I want to do this same exercise for `featureB.` too.**

Following is how I am expecting the output dataframe to look:

[image]

My post follows few approaches from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66273710/statistics-of-one-hot-encoded-columns-in-pandas-dataframe), but asks different questions.

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Is possible create `df2` in text?

Comment: jezrael: I added snippets for creation of `df2` and `df1` in the revised post.

Comment: Is numbers correct? I got different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is convert columns with `std` to `dfstd` for matching `df22` after splitting columns names by `_` in first level of MultiIndex and divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('label')
df2 = df2.set_index('label')

dfstd = df1.filter(like='std')
dfstd.columns = dfstd.columns.str.replace('_std','')
print (dfstd)
       featureA  featureB
label                    
cat       0.189      0.10
dog       0.274      0.17

df11 = df1.copy()
df11.columns = df11.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
print (df11)
      featureA                   featureB            
             1    2     3    std        1     2   std
label                                                
cat       0.60  0.2  0.20  0.189     0.40  0.60  0.10
dog       0.67  0.0  0.33  0.274     0.67  0.33  0.17

df = df11.div(dfstd, level=0)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
       featureA_1  featureA_2  featureA_3  featureA_std  featureB_1  \
label                                                                 
cat      3.174603    1.058201    1.058201           1.0    4.000000   
dog      2.445255    0.000000    1.204380           1.0    3.941176   

       featureB_2  featureB_std  
label                            
cat      6.000000           1.0  
dog      1.941176           1.0
```

---

```
df2 = df2.div(df).dropna(how='all', axis=1).fillna(0)
print (df2)
           featureA_1  featureA_2  featureA_3  featureB_1  featureB_2
label                                                            
cat         0.315       0.000    0.000000    0.000000    0.166667
cat         0.000       0.945    0.000000    0.000000    0.166667
dog         0.000       0.000    0.830303    0.253731    0.000000
```

Comment: jezrael: Checking the values now.

Comment: @Commoner - Because `1 / 0.189 = 5.291005`, if understand correct what need

Comment: Thanks for  the answer. I meant standard deviation divided by the corresponding column contained in df1. I am updating the picture for final dataframe now with the correct values. Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: Jezrael : Here is how the numbers in the final figure were obtainede: 

`0.189 / 0.6 = 0.315` , `0.189/0.2 = 0.945` , `0.274/0.33 = 0.8303` , `0.1/0.6 = 0.1667` , `0.17/0.67=0.253`.